# window.onscroll not working in Safari and iOS within Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, scroll, window, nuxt.js

I'm creating a sticky header and the following code works in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari (desktop) or on iOS.

```
mounted() {
  window.onscroll = () => {
    console.log('scrolling');
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
      this.scrolling = true;
    } else {
      this.scrolling = false;
    }
  };
},
```

I thought it might be a Nuxt `window` issue, but the fact is working in other browsers makes me think that it's not.

I've also tried

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  console.log('scrolling');
})
```

without success

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

`(document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0 || document.body.scrollTop > 0)`